# Docker folders creation and Kubernetes Volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a `docker` image that creates few folders and extract files into it like below

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/myapp/myappv4 \
             /home/myapp/myappv4/files \             
             /home/myapp/myappv4/files/logs \
             /home/myapp/myappv4/myappentries
WORKDIR /home/myapp
RUN chown -R myapp:myapp /home/myapp 

ADD /myapp-v4-files/*.zip /home/myapp/myappv4/files/
ADD /myapp-v4-files/init.txt /home/myapp/myappv4/myappentries/
ADD /myapp-v4-files/pro.json /home/myapp/myappv4/myappentries/
```

These folders and files needs to be accessed by other `containers` in a `pod` in `kubernetes`. Should i create `persistentvolume` in `kubernetes` and have these locations in them and copy the content from this `container` to this `volume`? In that way they would not get deleted right?. Since i am new to `kubernetes` i am not sure on how to achieve this. Transition from `docker container` to `kubernetes` deployment seems to be a confusing part for me,any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: "Sharing files" and "Kubernetes" tend to not go well together.  Are there other ways you could approach this?  For example, you could use this fragment as part of a base Docker image that's the `FROM` line of your other application images, you could fetch the files by HTTP, or you could store the files somewhere totally external to the cluster like Amazon S3.

Comment: These are all actually application files that needs to be started. Will it work?

Comment: Build the application code directly into the Docker image that's getting run (or run the same image with alternate `command:`).  Don't try to put application code in volumes or overwrite it at deployment time.

Comment: what if the `containers` want to have a common storage i.e i have 3 containers which needs `application files` to be accessed. Actually i want to have a `pod` with `3 containers` in them, but i got to know that i cannot scale them individually. So i am going for `multiple pods` which can be scaled individually as they have only one `container` in them and hence i need a `common storage` . Any other good way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share a set of directories between multiple containers in a single pod, using only *EmptyDir* volume will suffice. You don't need to use PersistentVolumes (unless you want persistence, meaning you want the data to survive pod restarts).

However note that adding a volume (a kubernetes construct) will overwrite the files already present in your container at the path where you are mounting the volume, kind of what happens with a layered filesystem that *docker* uses.

For your usecase, I think you can move the file fetching logic from the Dockerfile to a script that the pod will run, that will fix the above mentioned issue.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /cache
      name: cache-volume
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container-2
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /cache
      name: cache-volume
  volumes:
  - name: cache-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```

Read more about volumes [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir).

Comment: `docker image` has the application that runs inside a container. Should i move it to `persistentvolume` in `kubernetes` if i want that to be shared across `containers` and `pods`.

Comment: No, that'll not work. You'll need to add those files outside of your dockerfile. The docker image's own filesystem layers cannot be just shared across containers AFAIK. You'll need to populate your files in some other way:
1. Move the fetching of file in a script that runs when container starts.
2. Prepopulate a volume on a node with these files like EmptyDir, that the containers just mount.